# Problems enqeue scripts in wordpress (going nuts)

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm trying to enqeue a custom.js in my wordpress theme created from scratch. Here's what I have;

Here's what I have tried

```
functions.php

<?php

function add_theme_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_style('default-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/css/bootstrap.min.css');

    // Dequeue WordPress included jQuery
  wp_deregister_script('jquery');
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.min.js', array(), '3.0.0', true);


    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array('jquery'), null, true);

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_theme_scripts');
```

```
custom.js

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  const colorButton = document.getElementById('color-button');
  const colorDisplay = document.getElementById('color-display');

  const colors = ['color1', 'color2', 'color3', 'color4', 'color5'];
  let currentIndex = 0;

  function changeBackgroundColor() {
    document.body.className = colors[currentIndex];
    colorDisplay.textContent = getComputedStyle(document.body).backgroundColor;
    currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % colors.length;
  }

  colorButton.addEventListener('click', changeBackgroundColor);
});
```

Have tried to deqeue the built in jquery and enqeued the latest. Have tried the register and then enqeue variant as well but it just wont list out the javascripts when I look in the source code.

Have tried a simple variant where I just have

```
<?php

function add_theme_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_style('default-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/css/bootstrap.min.css');

    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array('jquery'), null, true);

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_theme_scripts');
```

The styles are there, the js wont show. What am I missing? It's a simple script that should change the background color on body when one click a button.

Answer (score 0):

Try unrooting your js in
`

```
jQuey(document).ready(function(){
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  const colorButton = document.getElementById('color-button');
  const colorDisplay = document.getElementById('color-display');

  const colors = ['color1', 'color2', 'color3', 'color4', 'color5'];
  let currentIndex = 0;

  function changeBackgroundColor() {
    document.body.className = colors[currentIndex];
    colorDisplay.textContent = getComputedStyle(document.body).backgroundColor;
    currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % colors.length;
  }

  colorButton.addEventListener('click', changeBackgroundColor);
});
})
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to work with

```js
function add_theme_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_style('default-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/css/bootstrap.min.css');

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_theme_styles');

function my_plugin_assets() {

    wp_register_script('customjs', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/custom.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
  wp_enqueue_script('customjs');

    wp_register_script('bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery') , '3.0.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-js');

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_plugin_assets', 100 );
```

and then

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  const colorButton = document.getElementById('color-button');
  const colorDisplay = document.getElementById('color-display');

  const colors = ['color1', 'color2', 'color3', 'color4', 'color5'];
  let currentIndex = 0;

  function changeBackgroundColor() {
    document.body.className = colors[currentIndex];
    colorDisplay.textContent = getComputedStyle(document.body).backgroundColor;
    currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % colors.length;
  }

  colorButton.addEventListener('click', changeBackgroundColor);
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).